Where does it say that Abraham rescues all Neshamos from gehinom?
I heard from a sephardic guy that Abraham rescues all Neshamos from gehinom. There is a caveat that he doesn't help those who sleep with a gentile woman. Does anyone know the source?

https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.19a.10

Thank you! Does the text mean relations alone or pulling forward the foreskin?

The source is in Gemara (Eruvin 19a):

״עוֹבְרֵי בְּעֵמֶק הַבָּכָא״, הָהוּא דִּמְחַיְּיבִי הָהִיא שַׁעְתָּא
בְּגֵיהִנָּם, וְאָתֵי אַבְרָהָם אָבִינוּ וּמַסֵּיק לְהוּ וּמְקַבֵּל
לְהוּ. בַּר מִיִּשְׂרָאֵל שֶׁבָּא עַל הַגּוֹיָה, דְּמָשְׁכָה עׇרְלָתוֹ
וְלָא מְבַשְׁקַר לֵיהּ.
Those who
are liable at that time for punishment in Gehenna, but our father
Abraham comes and raises them up and receives them. He does not leave
the circumcised behind and allow them to enter Gehenna, except for a
Jew who had relations with a gentile woman, in punishment for which
his foreskin is drawn, and our father Abraham does not recognize him
as one of his descendants. (Sefaria translation)


Excellent! Thank you.
